# Error in Querying sqlite-net db based on a date range

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, windows-phone-8

I have a problem for which I am writing one search query to do a search based on Date range which is in a **string** format.
The problem is I am not able to query between two date ranges I specify.

This is my query::

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Object WHERE (( TransactionAccount = '" + parameter + "') AND (CAST(Amount AS REAL) BETWEEN " + min_amount + " AND " + max_amount + ") AND Date BETWEEN   Date(2012-01-02)  AND  Date(2014-01-02)  ) ";

querylist = dbConn.Query<Passbook_transaction.Object>(query).ToList<Passbook_transaction.Object>(); ;
```

But its returning SQLite Exception.

The error seems to be in the "Date" because removing the date querying  works.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Date is the name of the function and the name of your column? I can see a conflict here. By the way, are you sure that Date (the function) requires just one parameter without the string quoting?

Comment: Hi, Now its not returning errors but the querylist size is shown as empty. even though there are transactions between those date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted out the issue by adding the date in db in format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"(which is accepted by SQLite) and using the query below:

```
 String query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Object WHERE (( TransactionAccount = '" + parameter + "') AND (CAST(Amount AS REAL) BETWEEN " + min_amount + " AND " + max_amount + ") AND TDate BETWEEN   Date('2014-01-01 19:45:46')  AND  Date('2014-02-01 19:05:43')  ) ";
```

Thanks all for comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

try this, quoting dates:

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Object WHERE (( TransactionAccount = '" + parameter + "') AND (CAST(Amount AS REAL) BETWEEN " + min_amount + " AND " + max_amount + ") AND Date BETWEEN   Date('2012-01-02')  AND  Date('2014-01-02')  ) ";
```